# How do I recognize a symlink in Dart when dealing with the Directory class?

Tags: directory, dart, symlink

When I instantiate a Directory in Dart, and that file exists, how can I check whether the Directory is a real folder, or just a symlink?

Comment: There is no support for symlinks. You can't create those, nor can you check if an entry is a symlink. Consider filing a new bug. The Pub package manager uses command line to create symlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you can recognize a symlink is if the path differs from the full path. Directory doesn't have `fullPath()` or `fullPathSync()`, but `File.fullPathSync()` works on directories. So you can do this:

```dart
bool maybeIsSymlink(String path) {
  var fullPath = new File(path).fullPathSync();
  return path != fullPath;
}
```

However this only works correctly when `path` is absolute, and none of its ancestors are symlinks. To work around that you can get the full path of the directory's parent, append the directory name and compare that:

```dart
bool isSymlink(String pathString) {
  var path = new Path(path);

  var parentPath = path.directoryPath;
  var fullParentPath = new File.fromPath(parentPath).fullPathSync();
  var expectedPath = new Path(fullParentPath).append(path.filename).toString();

  var fullPath = new File.fromPath(path).fullPathSync();

  return fullPath != expectedPath;
}
```

Note that I have not tested this, but I've dealt with symlinks a lot in Dart, and this should work. If `pathString` ends in '/' you'll have to remove it. I usually end up getting paths from a directory listing, so I track the expected path as I recurse down the directory structure.

You can see a special `listDirectory()` implementation that detects symlinks and sends `Symlink` instances to the stream along with `File`s and `Directory`s in a branch in buildtool: https://github.com/dart-lang/buildtool/blob/m4/lib/src/util/io.dart

Answer (score 1):

In bleeding edge, there now is a static FileSystemEntity.isLinkSync(path) methods that will tell you if something is a symlink; also when it is a broken symlink.

http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/FileSystemEntity.html

For operations on links we are adding a Link class. The code is out for review now:

https://codereview.chromium.org/12691002

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check from the command line to verify what is happening,
ls -al DIRNAME and check for 'l' in the permissions section, and examine what it's pointing "to" on the right side of the output.

see also man 1 stat

If you're wanting to check that from within Dart itself, I don't know how.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to check from Dart, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileSystemEntity.typeSync(path)
```

return an `FileSystemEntityType` with one of the values

- `FileSystemEntityType.DIRECTORY`
- `FileSystemEntityType.FILE`
- `FileSystemEntityType.LINK`
- `FileSystemEntityType.NOT_FOUND`